# How to deal with detached model when trying to update table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, attached-properties

This is what I am trying to do and currently getting error:

> ApplicationId is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

`ApplicationId` is the primary key in `Applicant` table.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var existingApplicant = db.Applicants.Where(x => x.LoginId == LoginId).FirstOrDefault();    
var attachedEntry = db.Entry(existingApplicant);
attachedEntry.Property(x => x.ApplicantId).IsModified = false;
attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedApplicant);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're telling the state manager that the Property has not changed and change it afterwards which marks it as changed.
Try swapping lines 3 and 4 so you'll set attachedEntry.ApplicantId to updatedApplicant.ApplicantId and then tell the state manage it has not changed.

If this doesn't work try saving the Id before you use SetValues and set it back to the old value afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Uh ... I forgot that updatedApplicant has new ApplicbntId which is different from ApplicantId in existingApplicant.

All I had to do is to say:
`applicant.ApplicantId = existingApplicant.ApplicantId;`